# Calling service layer directly from main class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a project structure controller -> response builder -> service layer.
Here service layer call the repository layer(database layer).

Everything is ok when follow the structure.

But,for testing i want to call the service layer directly from a java main class.

How can i do this??????

**My controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ishmam")
public class IshmamAddressController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ishmamAddressBuilder")
    IshmamAddressBuilder ishmamAddressBuilder;


    @RequestMapping("/getAddress")
    public IResponseDto<WebbCustomerAddressDto> getAllAddress(){
        return ishmamAddressBuilder.getAllAddress();
    }

}
```

**My builder class is:**

```
@Component("ishmamAddressBuilder")
public class IshmamAddressBuilder {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ishmamAddressServiceImpl")
    IshmamAddressInterface ishmamAddressService;

    public IResponseDto<IshmamAddressResponseDto> getAllAddress(){
    IResponseDto<WebbCustomerAddressDto> response=new 
               IResponseDto<WebbCustomerAddressDto>(); 
    try{
        //here i call the service layer
        List<String> addressList=ishmamAddressService.getAllAddress();

    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
    return addressList;
 }
```

**My service layer is:**

```
@Service("ishmamAddressServiceImpl")
@Transactional

public class IshmamAddressServiceImpl implements IshmamAddressInterface {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier("webCustomerAddressRepository")
    WebCustomerAddressRepository webCustomerAddressRepository;

    @Override
    public IshmamAddressResponseDto getAllAddress() {
        List<WebCustomerAddress> aList = new ArrayList<WebCustomerAddress>();
        List<WebbCustomerAddressDto> dtoWebCustomerAddressList = new 
                      ArrayList<WebbCustomerAddressDto>();

        IshmamAddressResponseDto ishmamAddressResponseDto=new 
                      IshmamAddressResponseDto();

        try{

            aList = 
            address.getAllAddress(1);//Calling database layer

             ishmamAddressResponseDto=//Doing something,not important for 
                                       //question
    }

    return ishmamAddressResponseDto;

}
```

**Now what i want is to call the service layer directly from the main class:**

```
public class Address{

     public void getAddress(){
           IshmamAddressServiceImpl i=new IshmamAddressServiceImpl();
           List<String> list=i.getAllAddress();
     }


     public static void main(String[] args){
           Address a=new Address();
           a.getAddress();
      }

}
```

This process is not working.How can i do this???????

Comment: Use junit for tests, not main class. If you want to run the Service logic fromthe main class you have to build an application context and get the Service bean from it.

Comment: You meant "This process is not working" - could be more specific? Any stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you use spring, you must **never** use new to build an object that should be managed by spring.

So you could:

- either do it manually, that means bootstrap an application context with the same intialization that it would have in your application and explicitely get a bean from it

  ```
  ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
      Class<?>... annotatedClasses); // if it is the way you use it ...
  IshmamAddressInterface i = ctx.getBean("ishmamAddressServiceImpl", 
      IshmamAddressInterface .class);
  ```
- or use the [Spring test framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#integration-testing) that does it automatically for you in Junit tests

  ```
  @WebAppConfiguration
  @ContextConfiguration(classes = ...)
  public class WebIntegrationTests {

      @Autowired
      @Qualifier("ishmamAddressServiceImpl")
      IshmamAddressInterface ishmamAddressService;
      ...
      @Test
      public void testGetAddress() {
          ishmamAddressService.getAddress();
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: @ContextConfiguration(classes = ...)   ......what is the parameter in (classes=..????)

Comment: @IshmamShahriar: It would be too long for a SO answer to explain how to make spring integration test with Junit, that's why I gave you a pointer to the nice Spring framework documentation. If you have'nt used it before, you should really read that doc.